# Axis Location TikZ Tkz-Euclide

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-euclide

I want to reproduce this graphic using [tkz-base](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tkz-base) and [tkz-euclide](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tkz-euclide) :[image: graphic]

But I strugle to print the Y axis on the left, as all the x's are negative.

Here's a MWE :

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzInit[xmin=-150000,
    xmax=0,
    xstep=10000,
    ymax=18,
    ymin=4,
    ystep=2]
\tkzDrawX\tkzLabelX[orig,step=50000]
\tkzDrawY\tkzLabelY[orig]
\end{tikzpicture}
```

All I have is :

[image: problem]

As you can see, the y axis is on the right while I want it on the left.

Comment: Might I suggest using PGFplots? As far as I know `tkz-euclide` is more designated to geometric drawings. And your plot seems to be quite easy with PGFplots...

Comment: @GuilhermeZanotelli The `tkz` collection also has `tkz-fct` for plotting stuff. The `\tkzAxe` stuff is defined in `tkz-base`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how to modify the `tkz` stuff to do that, but as mentioned in a comment `pgfplots` is a good package for plotting stuff. Here is a starting point:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  % set axis limits
  xmin=-150000,
  xmax=9000,
  ymin=0,
  ymax=18,
  % draw axis lines only on left and bottom (default is to make a box)
  axis y line=left,
  axis x line=bottom,
  % disable having a common scale factor for all ticklabels
  scaled x ticks=false,
  % separation between ticks on x-axis
  xtick distance={50000},
  % number of minor ticks
  minor x tick num=4,
  % disable having e.g. -1e5 as a tick
  xticklabel style={/pgf/number format/fixed}
]

% plot some random numbers, just for example
\addplot +[domain=-150000:0] {rnd*10 + 4};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to stick with `tkz-base` then the only way [that I can find] to do this is to reset your axes to be positive, and then put the labels in by hand.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-base}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tkzInit[xmin=0, xmax=150000, xstep=10000, ymin=4, ymax=18, ystep=2]
    \tkzDrawX[label={}]
    \tkzDefPoint(150000,3.8){C}\tkzLabelPoint[below](C){Actuel}
    \tkzDefPoint(100000,3.8){B}\tkzLabelPoint[below](B){$-50\,000$}
    \tkzDefPoint( 50000,3.8){A}\tkzLabelPoint[below](A){$-100\,000$}
    \tkzDrawY\tkzLabelY[orig=false]
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, if you do this you would need to adjust your data points so that the years are positive too.  I guess you can think of them as "years since 150,000 years ago". But as noted in the comments, you might find it easier to use `pgfplots`.